# Change Parent State from Child Component in React (No Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

**Context:**

I'm working on *vanilla* React and React Bootstrap (**no redux**) project to manage roles in my department. The list of roles is not really relevant but for context imagine: Admin, Manager, Trainer, and so on.

I have a parent component `<RoleContainer key={role} role={role} />` element that has the following state:

```
this.state = {
  collapsed: true,
  roleAttributes: [],
  roleMembers: [],
  isLoading: true,
};
```

Inside `<RoleContainer />`, there is a `<table/>` element that contains a `roleMembers.map` to loop through the `roleMembers` and render the table rows dynamically. So, for each role member, you get a table row.

**The Problem:**

I have a component called `<CreateMemberModal role={role} roleAttributes={roleAttributes} />` which is a child component of `<RoleContainer />` and it allows the user to `POST` a new `roleMember`.

Currently, I have to `POST` the new `roleMember` into the DB and then reload the page so the changes can reflect.

Is there an accepted way (not an anti-pattern or bad practice) without redux to update the `roleMembers` state property of the `<RoleContainer />` component from within the child `<CreateMemberModal />` when I `POST` a new user?

It would allow me to re-render just the `<RoleContainer />` that had a new role member, instead of reloading the entire page.

Comment: you post the new roles and then get the new role as the response,and provide a callback from parent component to the child component, then pass the new role (came as the response) after new role save, then in parent component push the new role to the roles

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to do this that you can point me to? When you say provide a callback, do you mean I pass a function through a prop from the parent to the child?

Comment: Thats right, kiranvj's answer is thing i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method in `<RoleContainer />` to update roleMembers

```
// bind this in constructor 
updateRoleMembers(newRoleMember) {   
   this.setState((prevState)=> {
       return {roleMembers : prevState.roleMembers.concat([newRoleMember])}
   }
}
```

Now pass this method to `CreateMemberModal`

```
<CreateMemberModal role={role} roleAttributes={roleAttributes} updateRoleMembers={this.updateRoleMembers} />
```

call like `this.props.updateRoleMembers(NEW ROLE MEMBER)` in `<CreateMemberModal` component whenever you have the new member role details

> Is there any documentation on how to do this that you can point me to?
> When you say provide a callback, do you mean I pass a function through
> a prop from the parent to the child?

Check the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was really useful. I did check the documentation and seems like it is an accepted practice. I though I had read that a child updating a parent state was not a good practice. What's your opinion about this?

Comment: @TheDaniel its the recommended way as per the docs to lift the state up to the parent. Its useful if we dont have redux and want to share state.

Answer (score 1):

You can get use of the callBack function...
I am assuming your structure will be something like this...

```
export class RoleContainer extends React.Component {
    this.state = {
    collapsed: true,
    roleAttributes: [],
    roleMembers: [],
    isLoading: true,
};

yourApiCallToUpdateRoleMembers = () => {
    apiCall().then(response => {
        this.setState({
            roleMembers: response // assuming response has the data
        })

    })
}

render(){
    return <>
        <table>
            {this.state.roleMembers.map(element => <tr></tr>)}
        </table>
        <CreateMemberModal role={role} roleAttributes={roleAttributes} /> // instead of this add a callback function also

        <CreateMemberModal role={role} roleAttributes={roleAttributes} successCb={yourApiCallToUpdateRoleMembers} />
    </>
}
}
```

And your child component is having the post call to update the data

```
export function CreateMemberModal(props) {
    makePostCall = () => {
        apiCall().then(response => {
            props.successCb()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response it was helpful. I ran into some issues but I was able to work it out after checking kiranvj response and thinking a bit about how my specific components work. Do you have an opinion formed about whether this concept of a child updating its parent's state is good or bad?